# JSON numbers Regular Expression

Tags: regex, json

I'm trying to write a regular expression for strings that are numbers in JSON. I'm still new to writing Regular expressions, I found a diagram of a machine for JSON numbers  [here](http://www.json.org/) , but I'm not sure how to attack it.

Here are some strings that should be found by the regex.
 "22", 
"55.75466",
"-44.565"
"55e-2"
"69234.2423432 E78"
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You should probably explain what you mean by "strings that are numbers in JSON", preferably with an example. "JSON numbers" is a little puzzling too.

Comment: According to json.org your final example shouldn't be considered a number due to the space.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For reference, here's the "number" diagram from http://www.json.org/fatfree.html:

[image: JSON number]

The regex that should match this is:

```
-?(?:0|[1-9]\d*)(?:\.\d+)?(?:[eE][+-]?\d+)?
```

Comment: could you, or someone explain to me how you got the answer?

Comment: I just followed the diagram, left to right. For example, first you choose between going down to encounter a `-`, or go straight, skipping the `-`. In regex this can be represented as `-?`, or, "Zero or one `-`s." Then, the path splits again, between a `0` and a series of digits starting with a `1` (so as to prevent numbers like `0123` since JSON doesn't support octal). In regex this can be represented by "alternation", which looks like this: ``(?:xxx|yyy)`` where `xxx` and `yyy` are possible "paths". And so on. If you need a deeper explanation of the regex, let us know.

Comment: neg sign "-" by itself is a valid json number according to your regex. would not bang

Comment: @drgs - The `(?:0|[1-9]\d*)` guarantees at least a digit. Still don't have to bang if you don't want, tho.

Comment: @kaizhu - Thanks. Hm, are you sure? That would only allow 2-digit (and higher) numbers...

Comment: @slackwing yea, turns out i'm wrong. deleted the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Andrew Cheong](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925913/andrew-cheong)'s fine [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13340826/3697870), here's a version that is **Bash**-compatible. The subtle differences take a while to get just right.

```
-?(0|[1-9][[:digit:]]*)(\.[[:digit:]]+)?([eE][+-]?[[:digit:]]+)?
```

In the end, the differences are just that `\d` is replaced by `[[:digit:]]` and the `?:` are dropped from the alternation clauses.

Here's a script you can paste into a Bash shell to verify its performance. The regex is surrounded by `^` and `$` to match the start and end of line respectively, to check for stray trailing or leading characters.

```
while read line; do
    if [[ $line =~ ^-?(0|[1-9][[:digit:]]*)(\.[[:digit:]]+)?([eE][+-]?[[:digit:]]+)?$ ]]
    then
        echo "$line is a number"
    else 
        echo "$line NOT a number"
    fi
done << END
1
-1
a
1a
a1
-1.0
1.
.0
.
-.0
+
+0
+.0
22
55.75466
-44.565
55e-2
69234.2423432 E78
69234.2423432E78
-
0123
END
```

In Bash 4.4.12, I get:

```
1 is a number
-1 is a number
a NOT a number
1a NOT a number
a1 NOT a number
-1.0 is a number
1. NOT a number
.0 NOT a number
. NOT a number
-.0 NOT a number
+ NOT a number
+0 NOT a number
+.0 NOT a number
22 is a number
55.75466 is a number
-44.565 is a number
55e-2 is a number
69234.2423432 E78 NOT a number
69234.2423432E78 is a number
- NOT a number
0123 NOT a number
```

Answer (score 0):

acheong87's answer should provide the regex that you require. However, if you are just trying to check if a string returned via JSON "is a number" then you can do this:

```
var valueAsString = "55e-2";
var isANumber = !isNaN(valueAsString);
```