# Extract Fractional Number From String

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string that looks something like this

`Hey this is my 1.20 string`

I'm trying to just extract `1.20` from it.

What's the best way to do this?

I've tried something like this, but I get the value of `1.20,20` rather than just `1.20`

```
var query = $(".query_time").html();
var matches = query.match(/\d.(\d+)/);
```

Comment: It's not exactly what you're asking about, but I think you have an error in your regex. "." matches all characters except for whitespace, so you'll end up matching something like "1 guy and 2 gals" as "1 guy and 2". I would also assume you want the decimal to be optional, no? Then it should be "/\d\.?(\d+)/"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of [the match function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is an array, not a string. So simply take

```
var nb = query.match(/\d.(\d+)/)[0];
```

BTW, you should also escape the dot if you want to have more precise match :

```
var nb = query.match(/\d\.(\d+)/)[0];
```

or this if you want to accept commas (depends on the language) :

```
var nb = query.match(/\d[\.,](\d+)/)[0];
```

But the exact regex will be based on your exact needs, of course and to match any number (scientific notation ?) I'd suggest to have a look [at more complex regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340717/json-numbers-regular-expression).

Comment: Great thank you. I will accept this answer once the time limit is reached.

Comment: This will match `Hey this is my 1!20 string`

Comment: @Bruno I'm not sure this was the exact topic of the question but I fixed the regex to be more restrictive, see edit.

Answer (score 1):

The value of `matches` is actually `[ "1.20", "20" ]` (which is an array). If you print it, it will get converted to a string, hence the `1.20,20`.

`String.match` returns `null` or an array of matches where the first index is the fully matched part and then whichever parts you wanted. So the value you want is `matches[0]`.

Comment: It should be matches[0] - the returned array is 0-based.

Comment: Ah, I see, I thought he wanted just the fractional part of the number.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
var nb = query.match(/\d\.\d+/)[0]; // "1.20"
```

- You need to escape `.` because that stands for any character.
- Remove the capture group (\d+) and the second match is not returned
- Add [0] index to retrieve the match

Comment: You still need the `0`-th index though. Relying on array-to-string conversion will come to bite you some day.